# UVM RAL: NULL pointer is dereference

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, uvm

I am a beginner in using UVM RAL. I am trying to access by DUT Registers using `UVM_BACKDOOR`. I think this should not require an adapter and a predictor. I maybe wrong thinking so.

Below is my code snippet:

```vhdl
class my_operations extends base_test;
    `uvm_component_utils(my_operations)

    `REG_BLOCK regmodel;

    task main_phase(uvm_phase phase)
        uvm_status_e    status;
        uvm_path_e      path = UVM_BACKDOOR;

        regmodel.MY_REG.MY_REG_SIGNAL.set(1'b1);
        regmodel.MY_REG.update(status, UVM_BACKDOOR);
        assert(status == UVM_IS_OK);   // <--- Error: NULL pointer dereference

    endtask // main_phase ends here
```

Please show me where am I wrong?

Comment: try using write method instead of update

Answer (score 0):

The  `` `REG_BLOCK regmodel `` may also be defined in base class `(base_test)` . If `base_test` has a value assigned to `regmodel` then extending it and redefining will overwrite that value.

Removing that line will work.